# Dynamically create unlimited section that consist of drop down list, text box, etc.) with Add button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a section on a form that when the user clicks on the "Add More" button, it will dynamically create that section on the page with the ability to create any number of that section on a page. The section consist of text fields, drop down fields, and text area. I am using .NET MVC 5 with JQuery.

The approach that I am looking at taking is that when the user clicks on "Add More" through Jquery, I am creating a string that represents the HTML for that section. I then associate that string with a DIV tag to show on the page.

I was wondering if there is any other approach anybody has used in the past.

Comment: jQuery can create elements in a few ways, e.g. `$("<div>")` would give you a `div` jQuery object. The vanilla JS equivalent would be `document.createElement("div")`. String concatenation is fine, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also render a partial view instead of writing directly html in jquery, your partial view should contain everything you need to add in your section, the partial view would render it with the jquery into click event :

example to give you an idea

```
$("#btnAddMore").click(function(){
var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetPartialViewMethod", "ControllerName))";
$("#sectionsContainer").load(url)
})
```

if you need your sections have a delete button, you should consider that as they are elements that are added after the DOM is rendered, Delegated events will be required